# moving an object in unity and stop on collission

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new at this, I'm trying to move an object a fixed amount of units but I want to stop doing so when I hit an obstacle, I would like to be able to move around the obstacle, I have trouble figuring out the triggers and rigid bodies
This is the code that moves my object

```
 if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        gameObject.transform.Translate(0f, 0f, 1f, Space.Self);
```

This works fine, the thing is that when I'm next to an object, depending on the collider or trigger It will push or merge with the object and I would like It to stop in that direction.

Comment: Sort of like crossy road when the player moves around and stops at obstacles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Translate method on the transform effectively teleports the gameObject to the next location, while ignoring any physics or collisions.  If using a CharacterController use the [Move](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) method, or if using a rigidbody use the [MovePosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) method.  Also, if a rigidbody is used on the player, it should be set to nonkinematic and immobile obstacles should have their rigidbodys set to isKinematic.

Comment: Thanks for that, it cleared some things but still cant make it work the way I want, I used CharacterCollider and moves and collides with the objects but if I try to move again against the object then my objects fly everywhere, I think my logic should be to detect collision and if collision detected than disable move towars that position rather than trying to move to that position and be stopped by physics, would that be correct?

Comment: Did you mean you used [CharacterController](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html)?  I recommend having a look at this link [Custom Character Controller](https://roystanross.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/custom-character-controller-in-unity-part-1-collision-resolution/)